# How can I replace Flutter widgets with canvas and vice versa?

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm making a 2D game using [Flutter Flame](https://github.com/luanpotter/flame). The library uses a canvas, as seen here:

```
start() {
  var previous = Duration.ZERO;

  window.onBeginFrame = (now) {
    var recorder = new PictureRecorder();
    var canvas = new Canvas(
        recorder,
        new Rect.fromLTWH(
            0.0, 0.0, window.physicalSize.width, window.physicalSize.height));

    Duration delta = now - previous;
    if (previous == Duration.ZERO) {
      delta = Duration.ZERO;
    }
    previous = now;

    var t = delta.inMicroseconds / Duration.MICROSECONDS_PER_SECOND;

    update(t);
    render(canvas);

    var deviceTransform = new Float64List(16)
      ..[0] = window.devicePixelRatio
      ..[5] = window.devicePixelRatio
      ..[10] = 1.0
      ..[15] = 1.0;

    var builder = new SceneBuilder()
      ..pushTransform(deviceTransform)
      ..addPicture(Offset.zero, recorder.endRecording())
      ..pop();

    window.render(builder.build());
    window.scheduleFrame();
  };

  window.scheduleFrame();
}
```

It's worth noting that Flutter Flame uses a custom `BindingBase`, similar to how the Widgets work.

```
class _CustomBinder extends BindingBase with ServicesBinding {}
```

This works great for the game, but I was hoping to use real flutter widgets for the main menu, settings pages, etc.

Is there a way to swap between these two contexts?

To provide an idea of what I'm looking for, I'd like there to exist these two functions:

```
loadHomeScreen(); // replaces the canvas, if any, with Flutter widgets
loadCanvasScene(); // replaces the Flutter widgets with the canvas
```

Comment: Canvas aren't even from Flutter. There's most likely a way, but not small enough to be answered in stackoverflow. Flutter's alternative is `CustomPaint`

Comment: That explains a few things. Unfortunately, I'm too far in to ditch the current library I'm using (class project) and reach parity quickly.

Comment: Flutter Flame has barely a month of existence.  Your project can't be _that_ big to the point where you can't go back right ?

Comment: No, no, it's not enormous but I've got other things to do. And it's not a huge priority project. I'm going to make an attempt tonight to try out https://github.com/vlidholt/flutter_sprites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the newer versions of [Flame](https://github.com/luanpotter/flame) (0.8.x), the game becomes a regular Widget, and thus support for apps that have regular widgets for menus and settings.

Start as a regular app, and in one of your build methods, add the widget of your game implementation:

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame {
  // your game here
}

// in your game screen class

final MyGame game = new MyGame();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return game.widget;
}
```

For a more in-depth example, check [this complete game](https://github.com/luanpotter/bgug), built using the latest version of Flame. The specific code you are looking for, that switches between game and app is [here](https://github.com/luanpotter/bgug/blob/master/lib/screens/start_game_gui.dart).